# change url for website content using php

Tags: php

I want to read the content of web page using php and preview it using iframe in HTML page,I make like this to avoid cross origin problems that avoid me to reach other websites content using javascript.

I want to replace each url in a website content using php, I want to replace all urls for src and href tags in HTML file.

for example I want to replace this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stackoverflow.com/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and the same for java script files and img and other tags.

Any one can help ?

Comment: Do you have only relative URLs or some of them are coming together with the protocol and server name?

Comment: I retrieve only the URL of the main webpage.

Comment: You could try to do this with regexes and I think it should be quite doable, but just too a bit too much work for me to do on a problem that may already be solved (as there are a lot of special cases to keep in mind when writing your regex)

Comment: I tried to use preg_preplace but I face many many problems, all problems are solved using @Cheery answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a simple solution by placing the following tag into the head section of the page?

```
<base href="http://stackoverflow.com/" />
```

ps: description http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @Alaa  It will 'tell' to follow all relative URLs using that href as a current location.